# Paypal rest api available in Ireland - Jan 2015?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Before I spend a load of time on this, I just want to check that the Rest API is available in Ireland.  Having inspected the page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/
it clearly show support for Euros, but the title of the page says Country and Currency Support and then  only seems to talk about Currency with no mention of Country support.  I know this is pedantic but does that mean the Country is irrelevant so any country that uses Euros is supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, REST API is just another platform which is supported for most of the [countries](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/country-worldwide).
You can always use Sandbox environment if you really want to make sure if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance!